# Not able to see the Azure Microsoft.classiccompute provider to register

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

Team,

I am using the CSP subscription. I need to create a cloud service  within the azure portal. But it gave me an red line saying that the "subscription not allowed to register Microsoft.classiccompute".

Is this because its using the CSP subscription ? Is there any workaround ?

I tried to find the "provider to register" to my subscription but cannot be found in the list to register it.

How do we possibly include the provider to my subscription or is it that CSP subscription is not allowed to register?

Do I have to use a Non CSP subscription.? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure CSP supports only the Azure Resource Manager model, the cloud service `Microsoft.classiccompute` is  classic deployment model, you need to use another subscription, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-solution-provider/overview/azure-csp-available-services).

> For example, because Azure CSP supports only the Azure Resource Manager model, non-Azure Resource Manager services are not available in the program.

Comment: Thanks Joy for your reply. That confirms. But any idea as to what might be the alternative to "using Cloud services"  as we have a complete cloud service ready with a web role and other storage mechanisms ready to be migrated to a CSP subscription

Comment: @user3276487 I am not sure, I recommend you to ask for the workaround in another post, it will be clear.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/overview

Cloud Services (Extended Support) is the ARM-based replacement for Microsoft.ClassicCompute cloud services.